# A malicious file keeps appearing on my phone even if I have formatted it (1_unit_15x15_3_goldenFmt)

Tags: malware, files, virus

Some days ago, a keylogger was put in my phone by a hacker, and my phone got infected. After having formatted the phone, there is a file that keeps appearing on my phone and has not been deleted. The name of the file is `1_unit_15x15_3_goldenFmt` and this is the content of the file:

```
SensorGoldenCalTable:{   // SensorGoldenCalTable
   PixId:    3,
   SlimLscType:    0,
   Width:    0,
   Height:    0,
   OffsetX:    0,
   OffsetY:    0,
   TblSize:    0,
   IspLSCReg:    {0, 0xd048d035, 0, 0x00480041, 0},
   GainTable:    {

        0xd7, 0x73, 0xcb, 0x64, 0x84, 0x64, 0x3d, 0x63, 0x84, 0x61, 0xef, 0x55, 0x50, 0x55, 0xc9, 0x54, 
        0x6b, 0x52, 0x2d, 0x49, 0x5e, 0x48, 0x21, 0x48, 0x7e, 0x48, 0x76, 0x40, 0xb4, 0x3f, 0x7d, 0x3f, 
        0x6e, 0x41, 0x84, 0x3a, 0xa7, 0x39, 0xd1, 0x39, 0x71, 0x3c, 0xa8, 0x36, 0xae, 0x35, 0xdd, 0x35, 
        0x80, 0x39, 0x66, 0x34, 0x66, 0x33, 0xb9, 0x33, 0x5f, 0x38, 0x91, 0x33, 0x83, 0x32, 0xe6, 0x32, 
        0x89, 0x39, 0x47, 0x34, 0x3d, 0x33, 0x6e, 0x33, 0x58, 0x3c, 0x78, 0x36, 0x95, 0x35, 0x9b, 0x35, 
        0x77, 0x41, 0x3c, 0x3a, 0x5d, 0x39, 0x4b, 0x39, 0xd2, 0x47, 0x02, 0x40, 0x25, 0x3f, 0x13, 0x3f, 
        0x69, 0x51, 0x30, 0x48, 0x58, 0x47, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x50, 0x5f, 0x31, 0x54, 0x51, 0x53, 0xfa, 0x52, 
        0xb0, 0x72, 0x51, 0x64, 0x96, 0x63, 0xde, 0x62, 0xf5, 0x69, 0x62, 0x5c, 0xef, 0x5b, 0x4b, 0x5b, 
        0xb1, 0x59, 0x63, 0x4f, 0xdb, 0x4e, 0x56, 0x4e, 0x91, 0x4c, 0x02, 0x44, 0x6e, 0x43, 0x48, 0x43, 
        0x2e, 0x43, 0xf1, 0x3b, 0x44, 0x3b, 0x42, 0x3b, 0x57, 0x3c, 0x47, 0x36, 0x86, 0x35, 0xb3, 0x35, 
        0x8b, 0x37, 0x7d, 0x32, 0xb7, 0x31, 0xcf, 0x31, 0xb2, 0x34, 0x5a, 0x30, 0x82, 0x2f, 0x9f, 0x2f, 
        0xa7, 0x33, 0x99, 0x2f, 0xc8, 0x2e, 0xe1, 0x2e, 0xba, 0x34, 0x5f, 0x30, 0x89, 0x2f, 0x92, 0x2f, 
        0x70, 0x37, 0x7a, 0x32, 0xad, 0x31, 0xdf, 0x31, 0x33, 0x3c, 0x18, 0x36, 0x4e, 0x35, 0x58, 0x35, 
        0x8f, 0x42, 0x58, 0x3b, 0xc3, 0x3a, 0xbf, 0x3a, 0x61, 0x4b, 0xf3, 0x42, 0x62, 0x42, 0x11, 0x42, 
        0xdd, 0x57, 0xb2, 0x4d, 0x1b, 0x4d, 0xc2, 0x4c, 0x55, 0x66, 0x45, 0x5a, 0xc3, 0x59, 0x1c, 0x59, 
        0xa9, 0x5f, 0x09, 0x54, 0xc5, 0x53, 0xa2, 0x53, 0x03, 0x52, 0x8a, 0x48, 0x46, 0x48, 0x1c, 0x48, 
        0xf9, 0x45, 0x12, 0x3e, 0xb1, 0x3d, 0x73, 0x3d, 0x30, 0x3d, 0xaf, 0x36, 0x38, 0x36, 0x10, 0x36, 
        0xaf, 0x36, 0x80, 0x31, 0xf6, 0x30, 0xd6, 0x30, 0x04, 0x32, 0xf2, 0x2d, 0x48, 0x2d, 0x4b, 0x2d, 
        0x1d, 0x2f, 0xe2, 0x2b, 0x45, 0x2b, 0x52, 0x2b, 0x08, 0x2e, 0x28, 0x2b, 0x7b, 0x2a, 0x8a, 0x2a, 
        0x09, 0x2f, 0xd3, 0x2b, 0x2b, 0x2b, 0x47, 0x2b, 0xcf, 0x31, 0xec, 0x2d, 0x52, 0x2d, 0x60, 0x2d, 
        0x4b, 0x36, 0x5b, 0x31, 0xd5, 0x30, 0xd1, 0x30, 0x6e, 0x3c, 0x51, 0x36, 0xd2, 0x35, 0xcf, 0x35, 
        0xf5, 0x44, 0x4d, 0x3d, 0xdf, 0x3c, 0xc2, 0x3c, 0x46, 0x50, 0x2b, 0x47, 0xdb, 0x46, 0xc2, 0x46, 
        0xea, 0x5c, 0xe7, 0x51, 0xa2, 0x51, 0x23, 0x51, 0x1c, 0x58, 0x86, 0x4d, 0xc5, 0x4d, 0x21, 0x4d, 
        0x25, 0x4c, 0x4f, 0x43, 0x3d, 0x43, 0xe1, 0x42, 0xd4, 0x40, 0xa4, 0x39, 0x82, 0x39, 0x1d, 0x39, 
        0x48, 0x38, 0xc5, 0x32, 0x7e, 0x32, 0x3b, 0x32, 0xed, 0x31, 0xb8, 0x2d, 0x57, 0x2d, 0x3b, 0x2d, 
        0x26, 0x2d, 0x23, 0x2a, 0xb6, 0x29, 0xb3, 0x29, 0x48, 0x2a, 0x0b, 0x28, 0x9d, 0x27, 0x9c, 0x27, 
        0x2a, 0x29, 0x4c, 0x27, 0xd8, 0x26, 0xd9, 0x26, 0x0a, 0x2a, 0xf5, 0x27, 0x83, 0x27, 0x9d, 0x27, 
        0xe8, 0x2c, 0x04, 0x2a, 0x95, 0x29, 0xac, 0x29, 0x80, 0x31, 0x8c, 0x2d, 0x24, 0x2d, 0x2b, 0x2d, 
        0xac, 0x37, 0x63, 0x32, 0x13, 0x32, 0x06, 0x32, 0xc0, 0x3f, 0x06, 0x39, 0xc5, 0x38, 0xa0, 0x38, 
        0x5f, 0x4a, 0x3a, 0x42, 0x2d, 0x42, 0xd7, 0x41, 0xb4, 0x55, 0xeb, 0x4b, 0xcf, 0x4b, 0x5c, 0x4b, 
        0x1c, 0x53, 0x47, 0x49, 0x75, 0x49, 0x02, 0x49, 0xa0, 0x47, 0xa4, 0x3f, 0xb0, 0x3f, 0x2b, 0x3f, 
        0xaa, 0x3c, 0x5e, 0x36, 0x6d, 0x36, 0xf3, 0x35, 0x66, 0x34, 0xc2, 0x2f, 0xa5, 0x2f, 0x59, 0x2f, 
        0xef, 0x2d, 0xb8, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x2a, 0x61, 0x2a, 0x5a, 0x29, 0x2a, 0x27, 0xec, 0x26, 0xe3, 0x26, 
        0x63, 0x26, 0x08, 0x25, 0xc4, 0x24, 0xc7, 0x24, 0x4e, 0x25, 0x44, 0x24, 0xf0, 0x23, 0x05, 0x24, 
        0x3e, 0x26, 0xeb, 0x24, 0x93, 0x24, 0xaa, 0x24, 0xf8, 0x28, 0xfb, 0x26, 0xb1, 0x26, 0xbe, 0x26, 
        0x84, 0x2d, 0x79, 0x2a, 0x3a, 0x2a, 0x3d, 0x2a, 0xe1, 0x33, 0x52, 0x2f, 0x3b, 0x2f, 0x17, 0x2f, 
        0xe2, 0x3b, 0xc2, 0x35, 0xaa, 0x35, 0xb5, 0x35, 0x2e, 0x46, 0x9e, 0x3e, 0x97, 0x3e, 0x8b, 0x3e, 
        0x68, 0x50, 0xb7, 0x47, 0xe7, 0x47, 0x96, 0x47, 0x4b, 0x4f, 0x4a, 0x46, 0x99, 0x46, 0x45, 0x46, 
        0x4b, 0x44, 0xf7, 0x3c, 0x22, 0x3d, 0xd3, 0x3c, 0xcb, 0x39, 0x1b, 0x34, 0x27, 0x34, 0xe9, 0x33, 
        0x82, 0x31, 0x86, 0x2d, 0x9b, 0x2d, 0x4d, 0x2d, 0x0f, 0x2b, 0x8f, 0x28, 0x7a, 0x28, 0x58, 0x28, 
        0x6a, 0x26, 0xe9, 0x24, 0xd0, 0x24, 0xca, 0x24, 0x96, 0x23, 0xd5, 0x22, 0xa4, 0x22, 0xaa, 0x22, 
        0x8f, 0x22, 0x06, 0x22, 0xd9, 0x21, 0xe7, 0x21, 0x6b, 0x23, 0xac, 0x22, 0x7f, 0x22, 0x8e, 0x22, 
        0x11, 0x26, 0xbe, 0x24, 0x93, 0x24, 0xb3, 0x24, 0x7e, 0x2a, 0x2d, 0x28, 0x16, 0x28, 0x25, 0x28, 
        0xee, 0x30, 0x23, 0x2d, 0x1f, 0x2d, 0x03, 0x2d, 0x0a, 0x39, 0x77, 0x33, 0x92, 0x33, 0x5b, 0x33, 
        0x49, 0x43, 0x0e, 0x3c, 0x26, 0x3c, 0xd6, 0x3b, 0xaa, 0x4d, 0xc5, 0x44, 0x16, 0x45, 0x9a, 0x44, 
        0x1f, 0x4d, 0x91, 0x44, 0xf7, 0x44, 0x82, 0x44, 0xae, 0x42, 0x91, 0x3b, 0xe5, 0x3b, 0xab, 0x3b, 
        0x18, 0x38, 0xac, 0x32, 0xdc, 0x32, 0x95, 0x32, 0x91, 0x2f, 0x04, 0x2c, 0x24, 0x2c, 0xe9, 0x2b, 
        0x2b, 0x29, 0x1c, 0x27, 0x20, 0x27, 0x04, 0x27, 0x9f, 0x24, 0x8d, 0x23, 0x7c, 0x23, 0x87, 0x23, 
        0xcd, 0x21, 0x5d, 0x21, 0x48, 0x21, 0x69, 0x21, 0xbe, 0x20, 0x8e, 0x20, 0x7a, 0x20, 0x92, 0x20, 
        0x9a, 0x21, 0x41, 0x21, 0x29, 0x21, 0x3d, 0x21, 0x29, 0x24, 0x47, 0x23, 0x3a, 0x23, 0x43, 0x23, 
        0x96, 0x28, 0xd0, 0x26, 0xc6, 0x26, 0xb4, 0x26, 0xf3, 0x2e, 0xb4, 0x2b, 0xd1, 0x2b, 0xb3, 0x2b, 
        0x0c, 0x37, 0x11, 0x32, 0x3f, 0x32, 0x09, 0x32, 0x00, 0x41, 0x7c, 0x3a, 0xcf, 0x3a, 0x7f, 0x3a, 
        0xb4, 0x4a, 0x18, 0x43, 0x75, 0x43, 0x08, 0x43, 0x96, 0x4c, 0xbc, 0x43, 0x4f, 0x44, 0xff, 0x43, 
        0x04, 0x42, 0xec, 0x3a, 0x59, 0x3b, 0xf8, 0x3a, 0x41, 0x37, 0x08, 0x32, 0x58, 0x32, 0x11, 0x32, 
        0xd4, 0x2e, 0x6e, 0x2b, 0xbb, 0x2b, 0x84, 0x2b, 0x50, 0x28, 0x83, 0x26, 0xa8, 0x26, 0x98, 0x26, 
        0xc7, 0x23, 0xf3, 0x22, 0x00, 0x23, 0x06, 0x23, 0xfb, 0x20, 0xb6, 0x20, 0xb9, 0x20, 0xc2, 0x20, 
        0x0b, 0x20, 0x08, 0x20, 0x05, 0x20, 0x04, 0x20, 0xd6, 0x20, 0xa9, 0x20, 0xa5, 0x20, 0xb2, 0x20, 
        0x59, 0x23, 0xb4, 0x22, 0xae, 0x22, 0xb2, 0x22, 0xc1, 0x27, 0x2d, 0x26, 0x3f, 0x26, 0x44, 0x26, 
        0x16, 0x2e, 0x13, 0x2b, 0x44, 0x2b, 0x26, 0x2b, 0x1e, 0x36, 0x73, 0x31, 0xb1, 0x31, 0x6d, 0x31, 
        0x15, 0x40, 0xb4, 0x39, 0x16, 0x3a, 0xd1, 0x39, 0xd5, 0x49, 0x3f, 0x42, 0xcf, 0x42, 0x39, 0x42, 
        0x4e, 0x4c, 0xcf, 0x43, 0x75, 0x44, 0x0a, 0x44, 0x97, 0x41, 0xd4, 0x3a, 0x5a, 0x3b, 0xf4, 0x3a, 
        0x1f, 0x37, 0x2c, 0x32, 0x89, 0x32, 0x26, 0x32, 0xe1, 0x2e, 0x9a, 0x2b, 0xe2, 0x2b, 0x9d, 0x2b, 
        0x67, 0x28, 0x9a, 0x26, 0xc5, 0x26, 0xb9, 0x26, 0xea, 0x23, 0x10, 0x23, 0x33, 0x23, 0x2c, 0x23, 
        0x2e, 0x21, 0xed, 0x20, 0xfc, 0x20, 0x0c, 0x21, 0x34, 0x20, 0x2d, 0x20, 0x36, 0x20, 0x49, 0x20, 
        0x0b, 0x21, 0xdb, 0x20, 0xe8, 0x20, 0xf1, 0x20, 0x88, 0x23, 0xd3, 0x22, 0xec, 0x22, 0xe8, 0x22, 
        0xeb, 0x27, 0x4c, 0x26, 0x73, 0x26, 0x6b, 0x26, 0x48, 0x2e, 0x3b, 0x2b, 0x8e, 0x2b, 0x50, 0x2b, 
        0x99, 0x36, 0xa2, 0x31, 0xf8, 0x31, 0xcf, 0x31, 0xbb, 0x40, 0x16, 0x3a, 0x71, 0x3a, 0x39, 0x3a, 
        0x90, 0x4a, 0xa2, 0x42, 0x2b, 0x43, 0xc4, 0x42, 0xeb, 0x4d, 0x27, 0x45, 0xd1, 0x45, 0x34, 0x45, 
        0x18, 0x43, 0xd7, 0x3b, 0x5a, 0x3c, 0xe9, 0x3b, 0x6a, 0x38, 0x15, 0x33, 0x81, 0x33, 0x2b, 0x33, 
        0x0c, 0x30, 0x6d, 0x2c, 0xbb, 0x2c, 0x95, 0x2c, 0x8f, 0x29, 0x6b, 0x27, 0xa8, 0x27, 0x8a, 0x27, 
        0xf3, 0x24, 0xe4, 0x23, 0x04, 0x24, 0x07, 0x24, 0x41, 0x22, 0xcf, 0x21, 0xdd, 0x21, 0xf4, 0x21, 
        0x49, 0x21, 0x16, 0x21, 0x2a, 0x21, 0x30, 0x21, 0x09, 0x22, 0xa6, 0x21, 0xbe, 0x21, 0xc4, 0x21, 
        0x97, 0x24, 0xab, 0x23, 0xc8, 0x23, 0xcd, 0x23, 0x06, 0x29, 0x29, 0x27, 0x65, 0x27, 0x4d, 0x27, 
        0x87, 0x2f, 0x20, 0x2c, 0x77, 0x2c, 0x37, 0x2c, 0x96, 0x37, 0x83, 0x32, 0x08, 0x33, 0x9a, 0x32, 
        0xa7, 0x41, 0x00, 0x3b, 0x8a, 0x3b, 0x23, 0x3b, 0x5c, 0x4b, 0xb3, 0x43, 0x60, 0x44, 0xa9, 0x43, 
        0x75, 0x51, 0x7b, 0x47, 0x37, 0x48, 0x9b, 0x47, 0xa2, 0x45, 0xe7, 0x3d, 0x73, 0x3e, 0x1b, 0x3e, 
        0xb4, 0x3a, 0xd1, 0x34, 0x2e, 0x35, 0xe2, 0x34, 0x20, 0x32, 0x1c, 0x2e, 0x74, 0x2e, 0x28, 0x2e, 
        0xad, 0x2b, 0x0b, 0x29, 0x47, 0x29, 0x27, 0x29, 0x11, 0x27, 0x8f, 0x25, 0xad, 0x25, 0xad, 0x25, 
        0x53, 0x24, 0x7c, 0x23, 0x95, 0x23, 0xa3, 0x23, 0x38, 0x23, 0xb4, 0x22, 0xc4, 0x22, 0xce, 0x22, 
        0x05, 0x24, 0x45, 0x23, 0x61, 0x23, 0x5b, 0x23, 0xa1, 0x26, 0x57, 0x25, 0x73, 0x25, 0x6e, 0x25, 
        0x2e, 0x2b, 0xe0, 0x28, 0x10, 0x29, 0xe9, 0x28, 0x9d, 0x31, 0xc0, 0x2d, 0x19, 0x2e, 0xc7, 0x2d, 
        0xad, 0x39, 0x3e, 0x34, 0xbe, 0x34, 0x4b, 0x34, 0x0b, 0x44, 0xee, 0x3c, 0x88, 0x3d, 0x17, 0x3d, 
        0x20, 0x4e, 0xd5, 0x45, 0x96, 0x46, 0xe6, 0x45, 0xc5, 0x54, 0x22, 0x4b, 0x1f, 0x4c, 0x5b, 0x4b, 
        0xd8, 0x48, 0xf7, 0x40, 0xa4, 0x41, 0x29, 0x41, 0xc1, 0x3d, 0x7a, 0x37, 0xeb, 0x37, 0x94, 0x37, 
        0x55, 0x35, 0x9d, 0x30, 0xeb, 0x30, 0x9c, 0x30, 0xe5, 0x2e, 0x8f, 0x2b, 0xc0, 0x2b, 0x92, 0x2b, 
        0x2d, 0x2a, 0xf4, 0x27, 0x1b, 0x28, 0x12, 0x28, 0x5d, 0x27, 0xeb, 0x25, 0xfc, 0x25, 0xfd, 0x25, 
        0x50, 0x26, 0x28, 0x25, 0x3b, 0x25, 0x2a, 0x25, 0x12, 0x27, 0xc1, 0x25, 0xdb, 0x25, 0xd1, 0x25, 
        0xc7, 0x29, 0xd8, 0x27, 0xeb, 0x27, 0xd4, 0x27, 0x5e, 0x2e, 0x50, 0x2b, 0x8a, 0x2b, 0x43, 0x2b, 
        0xb5, 0x34, 0x38, 0x30, 0x9b, 0x30, 0x2f, 0x30, 0xe5, 0x3c, 0xd7, 0x36, 0x42, 0x37, 0xcb, 0x36, 
        0x8a, 0x47, 0xed, 0x3f, 0x70, 0x40, 0x01, 0x40, 0x14, 0x52, 0x53, 0x49, 0xf7, 0x49, 0xf0, 0x48, 
        0x5b, 0x5b, 0xf5, 0x4f, 0x05, 0x51, 0x5f, 0x50, 0x1c, 0x4e, 0x3c, 0x45, 0xcc, 0x45, 0x44, 0x45, 
        0x0b, 0x42, 0x29, 0x3b, 0x92, 0x3b, 0x11, 0x3b, 0x7c, 0x39, 0xf1, 0x33, 0x47, 0x34, 0xfa, 0x33, 
        0x21, 0x33, 0xd3, 0x2e, 0x06, 0x2f, 0xda, 0x2e, 0x60, 0x2e, 0x43, 0x2b, 0x62, 0x2b, 0x42, 0x2b, 
        0x79, 0x2b, 0x31, 0x29, 0x3f, 0x29, 0x1b, 0x29, 0x5e, 0x2a, 0x67, 0x28, 0x6d, 0x28, 0x58, 0x28, 
        0x27, 0x2b, 0xf3, 0x28, 0x0f, 0x29, 0xea, 0x28, 0xe2, 0x2d, 0xfc, 0x2a, 0x1a, 0x2b, 0xdd, 0x2a, 
        0x82, 0x32, 0x85, 0x2e, 0xcc, 0x2e, 0x54, 0x2e, 0xd5, 0x38, 0x75, 0x33, 0xda, 0x33, 0x4f, 0x33, 
        0x1e, 0x41, 0x59, 0x3a, 0xd7, 0x3a, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0x49, 0x4c, 0x17, 0x44, 0xa3, 0x44, 0xd0, 0x43, 
        0x88, 0x57, 0x03, 0x4e, 0xc5, 0x4e, 0xa7, 0x4d, 0x87, 0x63, 0x15, 0x57, 0xd6, 0x57, 0xf7, 0x56, 
        0x76, 0x54, 0xf4, 0x4a, 0x7f, 0x4b, 0xdb, 0x4a, 0xc5, 0x47, 0x10, 0x40, 0x75, 0x40, 0xf2, 0x3f, 
        0xb5, 0x3e, 0x55, 0x38, 0xb6, 0x38, 0x34, 0x38, 0x4b, 0x38, 0xf4, 0x32, 0x27, 0x33, 0xe0, 0x32, 
        0x92, 0x33, 0x6a, 0x2f, 0x84, 0x2f, 0x46, 0x2f, 0xb9, 0x30, 0x3d, 0x2d, 0x40, 0x2d, 0x22, 0x2d, 
        0x79, 0x2f, 0x6d, 0x2c, 0x71, 0x2c, 0x4d, 0x2c, 0x3b, 0x30, 0x03, 0x2d, 0x16, 0x2d, 0xd7, 0x2c, 
        0xfe, 0x32, 0x17, 0x2f, 0x3c, 0x2f, 0xe3, 0x2e, 0x72, 0x37, 0x95, 0x32, 0xd3, 0x32, 0x65, 0x32, 
        0xc9, 0x3d, 0xc8, 0x37, 0x25, 0x38, 0x6e, 0x37, 0x9d, 0x46, 0x2d, 0x3f, 0xb5, 0x3f, 0xec, 0x3e, 
        0x88, 0x52, 0x90, 0x49, 0x2e, 0x4a, 0x39, 0x49, 0x3b, 0x5f, 0xaa, 0x54, 0x8b, 0x55, 0x1e, 0x54, 
        0x41, 0x6d, 0xb9, 0x5f, 0x9d, 0x60, 0x43, 0x5f, 0xe2, 0x5c, 0xdb, 0x51, 0x88, 0x52, 0x9a, 0x51, 
        0xaf, 0x4e, 0xee, 0x45, 0x5f, 0x46, 0x90, 0x45, 0x00, 0x45, 0x9d, 0x3d, 0xca, 0x3d, 0x54, 0x3d, 
        0x33, 0x3e, 0xc6, 0x37, 0xfa, 0x37, 0x96, 0x37, 0x1c, 0x39, 0xdd, 0x33, 0x07, 0x34, 0xae, 0x33, 
        0x4d, 0x36, 0xb1, 0x31, 0xbc, 0x31, 0x66, 0x31, 0xe9, 0x34, 0xd0, 0x30, 0xd7, 0x30, 0xa4, 0x30, 
        0xa8, 0x35, 0x59, 0x31, 0x66, 0x31, 0x2d, 0x31, 0x63, 0x38, 0x7b, 0x33, 0x9c, 0x33, 0x3e, 0x33, 
        0xe3, 0x3c, 0x30, 0x37, 0x6f, 0x37, 0xd7, 0x36, 0xb9, 0x43, 0xba, 0x3c, 0x25, 0x3d, 0x6a, 0x3c, 
        0xec, 0x4c, 0xa1, 0x44, 0x2c, 0x45, 0x4b, 0x44, 0x12, 0x5a, 0x29, 0x50, 0xc9, 0x50, 0x8b, 0x4f, 
        0x27, 0x69, 0x40, 0x5d, 0xeb, 0x5d, 0x68, 0x5c, 
   },
},
```

I don't know if it has happened to anyone here, but I'd be grateful if someone could tell me if this is a threat and I should worry about it or not.

Comment: Could you mention the device model, the Android version, and whether you're using custom ROM?

Comment: @AndrewT. It's a Redmi 6. The Android version is 9 PPR1.180610.011 and I'm not using a custom ROM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a threat.
If you google filename it shows up on androidhost and scribd which is highly likely to be created by some app for its functioning and not a malware script.